# getImageData() is only giving me 0 for the red, green, and blue values

Tags: javascript, arrays, pixel

I'm trying to get the pixel array from a 16 x 16 image with getImageData(). I will use that to make a map from larger tiles. For example, if the color of the the top left pixel is green, then on my actual game map there will be a grass tile at 0, 0. My code for getting the array:

```
function getData() {
map = new Image();
map.src = "./res/maps/sample.png";
ctxTemp.drawImage(map, 0, 0);

var temp = ctxTemp.getImageData(0, 0, 16, 16).data;
console.log(temp);

for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i+=4) {
    var red = temp[i];
        green = temp[i + 1];
        blue = temp[i + 2];
        alpha = temp[i + 3];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Must wait until the image is loaded. Works fine after attaching the code to `onload`.

```
function getData() {
    var map = new Image();
    map.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0);

        var temp = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 16, 16).data;
        console.log(temp);

        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i += 4) {
            var red = temp[i];
            green = temp[i + 1];
            blue = temp[i + 2];
            alpha = temp[i + 3];
        }
    };

    map.src = "./res/maps/sample.png";
}

window.onload = getData;
```

Comment: im now getting -- Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Comment: Are you running this over `file:///`? What's the URL for the image that you're using?

Comment: Browsers don't allow loading images and some other files on the `file` protocol for security reasons; and `getImageData` can only be called for stuff originating from the same domain, also for security reasons. Try running it on a localhost server with image existing locally.

Comment: Thank you, but now my imgMap[] is returning undefined. Here is all the files. Can you see if you can fix it? [https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0q85srfsbhhqfc/Random.zip?dl=0]

Comment: dont think i tagged you

Comment: The `generateMap` function is being called before the `map.onload` where `imgMap` is assigned values. You should learn how to debug JS using the Developer Tools. If you throw in a couple of `debugger;` statements in your code, it'll become apparent.